# Add Google Cache link to SO off line page

Tags: feature-request

While stackoverflow is offline you can still access the questions using Google Cache, as it says on the stackoverflow blog, the search engine is the primary entrance to stackoverflow.

I have the addon on chrome which lets you press a button and it will take you the google cache version, this great except clicking on a question on a google results page redirects you to the offline page (atm) so there's no time to click the button before the page loads.

Please could you add a "Or view the page you were going to on Google Cache" link. That way you can be doing the maintenance and we can be reading questions and find answers to our problems.

Thanks.

Comment: +1 - just contemplated accomplishing some transparent variant of offline browsing by other means [e.g. via the Stack Apps API](http://stackapps.com/questions/1/api-documentation-and-help), but your suggestion would be a most useful and pretty easy to implement improvement for these hopefully rare, yet utterly disruptive outages indeed!

Answer (score 1):

You can already do this by visiting and using the search dialog on http://stackexchange.com though.

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/search-all-stack-exchange-sites/

Given the rareness of acts of God like this (complete loss of power at datacenter) I don't think it's worth pursuing.

Comment: Yes I read that and used it, but it doesn't give the Google Cached link. I mean if you went to this link http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373078/hello-world-for-a-joomla-web-service

Comment: you could still get that question even if SO is offline. I'm certain you knew, but maybe you misunderstood, or I misunderstood your answer

Comment: I think he means while you're doing maintenance, not while you're offline.